# Sorting of multiple rows (being populated from JSON) based on the select dropdown value selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple rows which is getting populated from JSON. I am using for each loop for iteration.I have a select dropdown with four values with one being the default case. I want to sort the rows based on the values selected from the dropdown.For example- if dropdown value is 'x', sort with 'y' key from JSON.When the default value is selected,the page should be displayed as it is.

```
jsonData.jsonArray.sort(function(a, b) {
            if ($( "#custom-dropdown" ).val()=="Active") {
                return (b.status> a.status) ? 1 : ((a.status< b.status) ? -1 : 0);
            } else if ($( "#custom-dropdown" ).val()=="End date") {
                return (b.endDate > a.endDate) ? 1 : ((b.endDate < a.endDate) ? -1 : 0);
            } else if ($( "#custom-dropdown" ).val()=="Nearest end date"){
                return (b.endDate > a.endDate) ? 1 : ((b.endDate < a.endDate) ? -1 : 0);
            } else{
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

JSON-

```
 var jsonData={
  "status": "200", 
  "jsonArray": [
    {
      "startDate": "2014-05-27",,
      "status": "true",  
      "endDate": "2016-05-27",
    },
    {
      "startDate": "2012-05-27",,
      "status": "false",  
      "endDate": "2013-05-27",

    }
  ]
```

}
Select dropdown structure-

```
<div id="custom-dropdown">
             <select class="selectpicker">
                  <option data-divider="true">Default</option>
                  <option data-divider="true">Active</option>
                  <option data-divider="true">End date</option>
                  <option data-divider="true">Nearest end date</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Note: When selected dropdown value is Active then sort by status.
2.When selected dropdown value is end date then sort by end date in ascending order
3.When dropdown value is neares end date then sort by end date in descending order.
4.When dropdon vale is the default then sorting should not happen

Can anyone let me know what am i doing wrong as the sorting is not happening in the page.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the structure of your json? also, you are trying to sort an array. But, you are using objects inside the sort function. Put complete data to get help

Comment: I'm assuming you have set an `onchange` trigger for the `#custom-dropdown` that runs the sort function? Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gb5v6ta4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working for me. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gb5v6ta4/4/)'s a sample fiddle showing a simple stringification of the sorted data. I have just added a trigger to repopulate when the value in the dropdown is changed

```
$("#custom-dropdown").on("change", function() {
  populate(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonData = {
   "status": "200",
   "jsonArray": [{
     "startDate": "2014-05-25",
     "status": "true",
     "endDate": "2016-05-25",
   }, {
     "startDate": "2012-05-26",
     "status": "false",
     "endDate": "2013-05-26",

   },{
     "startDate": "2014-05-27",
     "status": "true",
     "endDate": "2016-05-27",
   }]
   }

  var json_sort = function() {
  var newjsonArray  = jsonData.jsonArray.slice(0);
     var custom_dropdown = document.getElementById('custom-dropdown');
     return newjsonArray.sort(function(a, b) {
         switch (custom_dropdown.value) {
           case 'Active':
             return (b.status > a.status) ? 1 : ((a.status < b.status) ? -1 : 0);
             break;
           case "End date":
             return (b.endDate < a.endDate) ? 1 : ((b.endDate > a.endDate) ? -1 : 0);
             break;
           case "Nearest end date":
             return (b.endDate > a.endDate) ? 1 : ((b.endDate < a.endDate) ? -1 : 0);
             break;
           default:
             return 0;
         }
       });
     }
```

Two errors from you, first one is that you were using the same array , so your default condition would fail always. Remember Javascript is always pass by reference . So i cloned the array and returned . Next condition in "End Date" the conditional arrow must be in the opposite direction to sort in the opposite direction. Rest sorting is working fine . Ckeckout this working jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/a9vsfrbx/8/